# what you want to evaluate and if [Consommation Moyenne] is a hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx

hello how to calculate kpi with iff
for exemple if IIF ([Measures].[Consomation Energie]) >[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne]
msg bad consumption
else good consumption

Comment: And `kpi` is? There's too many TLAs to even try and guess what you're trying to get at. Kilograms per inch? Kansas Pro-Independence?

Comment: I want just  to compare between consumption and consumption average and I Know my syntaxe is false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
IIF ([Measures].[Consomation Energie] > [Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne],
     "bad consumption",
     "good consumption")
```

Comment: i am try it if don't add KPI It works http://hpics.li/0c06e11 but if add kpi  http://hpics.li/d7b370f

Comment: What do you mean if you don't add KPI? Adding a KPI in SSAS cube structure?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare the `[Measures].[Consomation Energie]` to the value of the key of member `Two` of the `[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne]` attribute hierarchy, then you would use something like

```
IIF ([Measures].[Consomation Energie]
      >
     [Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne].[Two].Properties("Key0", TYPED),
     -1,
     1)
```

If you want to show a KPI, the value should be numeric (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174875.aspx).

Comment: thank you but there is an error after [Consommation Moyenne], exactly ,

Comment: You need to remove the closing bracket after the [Measures].[Consomation Energie].

Comment: @user3642654 I assume there is a problem with the condition. I just took what you wrote. And that does the following, assuming `[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne]` is a hierarchy: Evaluate the measure `Consomation Energie` for the default member of `[Consommation Moyenne]` (presumably the `All` member), and check if it is greater than the value of the default measure (presumably the first measure defined in your cube) for the default member of `[Consommation Moyenne]`. Please edit your question to clarify what you want to evaluate and if `[Consommation Moyenne]` is a hierarchy.

Comment: I edit in my question therefore What is the solution [Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne] IT's dimension and Consomation Energie mesaure

Comment: @user3642654 I still do not understand what you want to calculate. Could you explain in clear words  to someone not knowing your cube what your request is? Which member of the dimension do you want to compare?

Comment: I want to compare between energy measurement and the average consumption if energery > average goof consumption else bad consumption

Comment: @user3642654 Is `[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne]` a hierarchy or attribute, or a member?

Comment: [Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne] is attribute

Comment: @user3642654 And which member of this attribute contains the average consumption? And is the key of this attribute numeric? And is its value the average with which you want to compare?

Comment: @user3642654 I edited my answer, putting my understanding from your comments into the assumptions in the begin of the answer.

Comment: @user3642654 This is really difficult: Without seeing the cube, just guessing and "remote debugging via questions and answers". Anyway: Is `[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne].[Two]` a valid member name? Is the key of this attribute numeric? If you define `[Dim Consommation Moyenne].[Consommation Moyenne].[Two].Properties("Key0", TYPED)` as a calculated member, is that NULL as well?

Comment: i am try it if don't add KPI It works hpics.li/0c06e11 but if add kpi hpics.li/d7b370f

Comment: @user3642654 Ok, so it seems everything worked if you defined the calculation as a measure, but there are problems if you use it as a KPI? Then, probably, the issue is that you use strings as the result, which is totally acceptable for a calculated measure, but not for a KPI. I adapted my answer.